# Tree Postorder Traversal performance

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I tried to work on my own to get iterative postorder traversal. My solution got Time Limited Exceeded in [Leetcode Online Judge](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-postorder-traversal/)

```
public List<Integer> postorderTraversalIterativel(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> ret = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode cur = root;
    while (cur != null || !stack.isEmpty()) {
        if (cur != null) {
            stack.push(cur);
            cur = cur.left;
        } else {
            TreeNode parent = stack.peek(), child = null;
            if (parent.right == null) {
                // pop hard
                stack.pop();
                while (parent.right == child && !stack.isEmpty()) {
                    child = parent;
                    ret.add(child.val);
                    parent = stack.pop();
                }
            } else {
                cur = parent.right;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

while the official implementation from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) could pass the test.

```
public List<Integer> postorderTraversalIterativel(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> ret = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode cur = root, lastVisited = null;
    while (cur != null || !stack.isEmpty()) {
        if (cur != null) {
            stack.push(cur);
            cur = cur.left;
        } else {
            TreeNode parent = stack.peek();
            if (parent.right != null && lastVisited != parent.right) {
                // make sure pop all the node has right child of the
                // previous pop
                cur = parent.right;
            } else {
                stack.pop();
                ret.add(parent.val);
                lastVisited = parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

by inspecting the code, I am unable to see why my implementation is slower than the official one. Could anyone point out what's happening? (It's possible that my solution is logically wrong, but the one failed my solution in timing I have unit tested, and the unit test finishes quick ...). Any comments are welcome.

```
public void testPostorderTraversal1() {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(3);
    TreeNode right = new TreeNode(1);
    TreeNode rightLeft = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right = right;
    right.left = rightLeft;

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);

    assertEquals(list.toString(), sut.postorderTraversal(root).toString());
}

public void testPostorderTraversal2() {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
    TreeNode right = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right = right;

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);

    assertEquals(list.toString(), sut.postorderTraversal(root).toString());
}
```

Comment: Why is parent.right==child in  while (parent.right == child && !stack.isEmpty()) required? you can get to the while loop only if (parent.right == null) evaluates to true and you are setting child to null before that, therefore parent.right and child are both always null at that stage, so that always evaluates to true I guess. That doesn't make your code exceed time limit, but just found it

Comment: @Kartik_Koro I am changing parent and child inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has possible to do Infinite loop.

Your 'testPostorderTraversal1' unitest is not finish.

If there is any node that has right child node that has left child node, can't finish.

Comment: ! thought it was passing the test. Will test asap - -.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang please see message "Time limit exceeded #stdin #stdout 5s 408704KB"

Comment: where do you see the message?